# Put select displays to sleep temporarily in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

This is my first post here. I have a tri-display setup: 2 computer monitors (ASUS, DVI to HDMI) and a TV (Sony, HDMI).

I lay in bed and watch all my media (TV shows/movies in MP4/MKV) on my TV and I find it to be very distracting when the other two monitors are on, so I manually turn them off.

I would like to know if there is a way I can do this temporarily with a script or a program. I also know how to code a bit (very rusty) so I can write my own if someone can point me in the right direction.

So in essence putting 2 displays to sleep while keeping the other display on.

Thanks.

Comment: See the answer to this question which uses C# (can be adapted to Visual Basic): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705019/c-sharp-selectively-turn-off-monitor